# django.db.utils.OperationalError: 3780 Referencing column and referenced column are incompatible

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration

I'm trying to add a foreign key relation between two models in Django, but I'm getting this error.

`Notification` model:

```py
class Notification(models.Model):
    ...
    lab_extension = models.ForeignKey(Labs, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, to_field='lab_id')
    ...
```

`Lab` model

```py
class Lab(models.Model):
    ...
    lab_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

After assigning this foreign key field to the `Notification` model, I get this error when doing `python manage.py migrate`:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3780, "Referencing column 'lab_extension_id' and referenced column 'lab_id' in foreign key constraint [constraint name] are incompatible.")
```

It's likely this error will not persist if I remove `AutoField` from the `Lab` model, and use the default id field. But I'm at a point into the project where I can't do that. I also realize a foreign key field is generally not nullable, but for this project, the `Notification` model may or may not point to a `Lab` model.

Doing `SHOW CREATE TABLE notification` gives me this:

```sql
notification_notification, CREATE TABLE `notification_notification` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `submission_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_request_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lab_extension_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `notification_notific_user_id_e9d6f5f4_fk_user_mana` (`user_id`),
  KEY `notification_notification_question_id_af1ad55d_fk_qa_question_id` (`question_id`),
  KEY `notification_notific_submission_id_78f78d05_fk_community` (`submission_id`),
  KEY `notification_notific_update_request_id_39cf03ba_fk_community` (`update_request_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `notification_notific_submission_id_78f78d05_fk_community` FOREIGN KEY (`submission_id`) REFERENCES `community_communitysubmission` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `notification_notific_update_request_id_39cf03ba_fk_community` FOREIGN KEY (`update_request_id`) REFERENCES `community_submissionupdaterequest` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `notification_notific_user_id_e9d6f5f4_fk_user_mana` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_manager_user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `notification_notification_question_id_af1ad55d_fk_qa_question_id` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `qa_question` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3241 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Doing `SHOW CREATE TABLE lab` gives me this:

```sql
lab, CREATE TABLE `lab` (
  `lab_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `project_dir` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '/opt/PacketAccess/',
  `lab_model` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `project_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pn_account` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `deployed` int NOT NULL,
  `progress` int NOT NULL,
  `request_time` int NOT NULL,
  `deploy_time` int NOT NULL,
  `destroy_time` int NOT NULL,
  `user_ip` varchar(260) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `labRegion` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EWR1',
  `pn_progress` int NOT NULL,
  `pn_project_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n/a',
  `pn_host_name` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `pn_device_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pn_device_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pn_sdn_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pn_nfmp_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pn_flow_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pn_nfmt_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pn_nrcx_ip` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  `pn_nrcs_ip` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  `pn_elastic_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `lab_version` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '17.3',
  `lab_tags` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n/a',
  `voucher_id` int NOT NULL,
  `admin_password` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `oss_password` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `deployed_email` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `lab_name` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_lab_ip` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  `deployment_test` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ssl_enabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `associated_lab_id` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lab_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11995 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

NOTE: I altered the names of some tables and fields on this post to protect privacy, so if some names are inconsistent, please ignore that.

Comment: How did you create the lab Model? What is the type of lab_id field in DBMS?

Comment: This is what I see in information schema for these fields:

[image1](https://ibb.co/6ntwpd9).
[image2](https://ibb.co/QPVKFCK).

Looks like it's int for both.

Comment: Can you add the table structure using ‘show create table table_name’ for both tables in question.

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby added the create table scripts to the post.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was in **Collation**.

I checked the Collation of the first table as:

```
select column_name, COLLATION_NAME, CHARACTER_SET_NAME from information_schema.`COLUMNS` where table_name = "<table_name>";
```

Then fixed the default database collation as:

```
alter database <database_name> CHARACTER SET <utf8mb4> COLLATE <utf8mb4_desired_value>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the probem,

In Lab table

```
  `lab_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

While in Notification

```
lab_extension_id` int DEFAULT NULL
```

These fields are different and can not be set to foreignKeys, move one type to the other.