# django.db.utils.OperationalError 3780 - Referencing column and referenced column "id" in foreign key constraint are incompatible

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

After reading this [django.db.utils.OperationalError: 3780 Referencing column and referenced column are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989992/django-db-utils-operationalerror-3780-referencing-column-and-referenced-column) and [SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63585525/sqlstatehy000-general-error-3780-referencing-column-user-id-and-referenced)

I have two models in Django 3.2.16 declared in different apps, it's a long time project which started in Django 2.2 and was upgraded over time.

Here are the two model classes:

from city_search.models

```
class Città(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length = 50, db_index = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.nome,self.regione)
    provincia = models.ForeignKey(Provincia, models.SET_NULL, blank=True,null=True)
    capoluogo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    regione = models.ForeignKey(Regione, models.SET_NULL, blank=True,null=True, related_name='comuni')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    latlng = LocationField(null=True,map_attrs={"center": [2.149123103826298,41.39496092463892], "zoom":10})
```

from eventos.models instead, which I'm developing

```
from schedule.models import events

class Manifestazione(events.Event):
    ciudad =  models.ForeignKey('city_search.Città', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Ciudad', related_name='manifestaciones', blank=False, null=False)
```

The migration of the latter model fails with the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3780, "Referencing column 'ciudad_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'eventos_manifestazio_ciudad_id_74f49286_fk_city_sear' are incompatible.")
```

these two models declarations translate to the following MySQL tables (the second is only partially created by the faulty migration)

```
mysql> describe city_search_città;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nome         | varchar(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| provincia_id | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| capoluogo    | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| regione_id   | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| slug         | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| latlng       | varchar(63) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> describe eventos_manifestazione;
+--------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| event_ptr_id | int    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ciudad_id    | bigint | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I absolutely understand that `int` and `bigint` are a great deal of difference. However I already tried to set `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'` in settings.py before making the migrations and later migrating, to no avail.
According to [Django Docs on automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) I could also try to use the AppConfig so I also edited eventos/apps.py like this and later migrated

```
class EventosConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
    name = 'eventos'
```

which didn't work either. I still get the same table schemes as above.

This is the migration that such settings generated.

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('city_search', '__first__'),
        ('schedule', '0014_use_autofields_for_pk'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Manifestazione',
            fields=[
                ('event_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='schedule.event')),
                ('ciudad', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='manifestaciones', to='city_search.città', verbose_name='Ciudad')),
            ],
            bases=('schedule.event',),
        ),
    ]
```

As I also read about a possible collation issue I will compare the table collations below:

```
mysql> select column_name, COLLATION_NAME, CHARACTER_SET_NAME from information_schema.`COLUMNS` where table_name = "city_search_città";
+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  | COLLATION_NAME    | CHARACTER_SET_NAME |
+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| id           | NULL              | NULL               |
| nome         | latin1_swedish_ci | latin1             |
| provincia_id | NULL              | NULL               |
| capoluogo    | NULL              | NULL               |
| regione_id   | NULL              | NULL               |
| slug         | latin1_swedish_ci | latin1             |
| latlng       | latin1_swedish_ci | latin1             |
+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> select column_name, COLLATION_NAME, CHARACTER_SET_NAME from information_schema.`COLUMNS` where table_name = "eventos_manifestazione";
+--------------+----------------+--------------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  | COLLATION_NAME | CHARACTER_SET_NAME |
+--------------+----------------+--------------------+
| event_ptr_id | NULL           | NULL               |
| ciudad_id    | NULL           | NULL               |
+--------------+----------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**My hypothesis**

1. is it more likely that the `int` and `bigint` difference is to blame
   and I'm unable due to some bug or weird reason that the migrations
   are ignoring my preference to shift to `int` as the automatic
   primary key fields?
2. Does it have to do with some difference in using these settings when it comes to foreign keys?
3. Or do you believe it may have more to do with the collation difference? But are there differences that I may not be able to see?

I'm unable to complete a proper migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error text was warning about the wrong table. It all worked fine by adding `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'` to settings.py and make new project-wide migrations that included some tweaks to a third app's model fields, where indeed `models.AutoField` was set to the `id` fields/columns.

This third app and the one I'm developing are not connected directly through a ForeignKey, I don't understand where the relation is, although the error turned up after I created the models I mentioned in this thread. So, honestly I'm not very sure why it worked or what these third models may have to do with this new app I'm adding to the project. I would really like to know if somebody understands more.